# Are there any benifits of Automated test data generator?

Tags: automation, test-data

In our testing team we are planning for a automated test data generator tool. I am not sure what are it's benefits. is it good to invest time in a test data generator tool?

In one of the case, we cannot use the production data, so we need data at our testing environment every time we create/deploy/restore build. for this situation is it good to go with a test data generator tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate JSON formatted test data using free online service. [Rest Ipsum](https://restipsum.com)